# Nagios client/plugins installation

Tags: nagios

I have installed Nagios on CentOS 6.8, nagios core + plugins. That means centos68 is now my nagios server. Now If I want to monitor another host say ubuntu, I should only install plugins on that server if I am not wrong ?

Kindly advise if I am wrong.

Comment: You are not obviously wrong. Nagios core is only required on the nagios server. Most nagios features work without installing anything on any other servers, but there are some things that require special nagios services running on monitored servers. What plugins are you talking about?

Comment: I installed nagios core + plugins as per here https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/Installing_Nagios_Core_From_Source.pdf#_ga=1.246667780.1471708323.1465398477

on CentOS

Now on another server which is Ubuntu installed just plugins but that server is not coming on nagios core http://localhost/nagios

Comment: From there, try the nagios web site that has been installed on the server (as per the instructions under "Nagios Web Interface"), then maybe your best bet is the Nagios forum. But if you're new to nagios, you might be better off installing a centos package than doing it all from source. Eg https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-on-centos-6

Comment: Got it installed , all good now. Had  to dig a lot but I think it was all well worth the effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the Nagios plugins on the Nagios server and install the Nagios NRPE agent on the servers you want to monitor.

```
cd /tmp
wget https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/agents/linux-nrpe-agent.tar.gz
tar xzf linux-nrpe-agent.tar.gz
cd linux-nrpe-agent
./fullinstall
```

The above will

- Modifying the distro's package manager repositories
- Installing prerequisite packages
- Creating required uses and groups
- Defining services for xinetd
- Compiling and installing the agent and plugins
- Configuring the firewall
- Configuring the agent

The script will stop to prompt you once, to ask for the IP address of your Nagios server. After installing the NRPE agent you can use check_nrpe on the Nagios server to run the plugins remotely and return the result.

```
./check_nrpe -H ubuntu-server -c check_uptime
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04) site. It cover Nagios server installation and setup for monitoring remote host.
Standard setup is installing NRPE daemon on remote servers together with plugins.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `check_by_ssh` plugin, if you do not want to install NRPE on targets.